# Matlab triangulation using DelaunayTri

Tags: matlab, delaunay

I would like to obtain the following triangulation in Matlab using the command DelaunayTri:

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
xgrid = [-0.5233   -0.3488   -0.1743    0.0001    0.1746    0.3490    0.5235];
ygrid = [-0.1745      0.3054    0.5454    0.7853];
[Xm,Ym] = ndgrid(xgrid,ygrid);      

DT      = DelaunayTri(Xm(:),Ym(:));
```

However, this generates the following triangulation:

[image]

Any ideas how I can adjust my code, such that I obtain the required triangulation?

Comment: Your target image can't be found with a delaunay triangulation because the point at (1/2, 1/6) for example sits on the edge of a triangle which can't happen using delaunay triangulation I'm afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use delaunay triangulation I'm afraid. However if you break you target image into 6 squares then there are only two patterns you need to create. You've already proved capable of creating both. I suggest you create each of these pattern templates and then just tile then by adding constants.